# Is it possible to download the demographic data day by day in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

When checking demographics data in GA, I can see each day's detailed data by moving the cursor over the graph. But how can I download a full version of that data? I tried export data but it only downloads the overall data.

For example, this is what I need:

```
| date    |  male  |  female |
|---------|--------|---------|
| Apr 11  |  209   |   248   |
| Apr 12  |  311   |   325   |
| Apr 12  |  340   |   467   |
```

Thanks for any kind of tips.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite possible, since "male" and "female" are dimensions, not metrics - i.e. you do not have "209 of male". But you might have 209 sessions by male visitors, which might be very well what you mean.

However you cannot export the male and female values as separate columns (this is one dimension "gender"). This would only work if you had a custom metric "gender" that you update yourself.

You can however have a report that looks pretty close to what you want. Create a custom report with date as dimension and pageviews, or sessions as metric.

Then click the pivot symbol above the table (marked yellow in the screenshot). Set "Pivot by" to "gender".  This looks rather like your report - but this view cannot be exported to excel, only as PDF. If you need the Pivot table in a spreadsheet your best bet might be a Google Spreadsheet with a bit of apps script.

[image]